# How to access virtualbox's host localhost from guest browser

Tags: windows, virtualbox, hosts

So it's 2019, I am running a Win 10 in my VirtualBox. And I want to basically redirect localhost to 10.0.2.2 (which is the host machine's ip)

```
10.0.2.2 localhost
```

This does not seem to work, some people have reported that Window 10 intentionally disables looking up of localhost. Not sure why they would do that.

But I am trying to find a work around that can resolve this issue so that I can access my host localhost urls.

Comment: What service exactly do you have running on the VM?  Why exactly do you want to redirect it to 10.0.2.2?

Comment: I am running a angular http server that serves my app. Now services on and off the machine requires the app to be running on a `localhost` origin. So I can't run it on 10.0.2.2, b/c services would unable to reconcile with that domain.

Comment: Why don't you use a different hostname all together to get around the localhost limitation?  You shouldn't be trying to refer to another machine as `localhost` that is supposed to be reserved for the local machine.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you might have missed the point, the question was how? not why? But to summarize, cors, url configurations, ssl, etc. So a number of things based on what I currently know.

Comment: *"Not sure why they would do that."* - `localhost` is extremely well-defined. In theory, it always points to the local machine, specifically the loopback network interface (which bypasses any local network interface hardware). It's also worth pointing out that indivdual software applications may map localhost internally to 127.0.0.1, so changes to e.g. the `hosts` file would be meaningless in those cases.

Comment: @Anaksunaman But I wouldn't have any other concerning apps that doing so could damage, as it is a VM I spun up to test specifically on IE. I get your points about why we should not mess with localhost, I do, I just don't understand when did stackexchange became this platform where questions gets a "why ask" instead of a solution.

Comment: It has _always_ been such a platform. Probably half the questions require understanding OP's intent before a _good_ solution can be provided. Sometimes it even turns out that what OP wants is the opposite of what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

> Now services on and off the machine requires the app to be running on a localhost origin. So I can't run it on 10.0.2.2

Configure a TCP or HTTP proxy / forwarder that listens on the VM's `localhost` and forwards the actual connections to the correct destination.

For HTTP, a reverse proxy such as Nginx or Apache would be the easiest approach. You would literally just need a VirtualHost with `ProxyPass / http://10.0.2.2/`. For other protocols both Nginx and HAproxy also support stream forwarding.

You could also use any other TCP forwarder, such as SSH's `-L` or `-R` forwarding (depending on whether the host or the guest has an SSH server), or even Windows' built-in `netsh int portproxy`.

For example, to forward port 443 on the Windows guest:

```
netsh interface portproxy add listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=443 connectaddress=10.0.2.2 connectport=443
```

Alternatively, if the guest has PuTTY installed and the host has an SSH server:

```
plink -v -N -L 443:localhost:443 user@10.0.2.2
```

> some people have reported that Window 10 intentionally disables looking up of localhost. Not sure why they would do that

There are two main reasons in general why Windows might have done that:

1. The name `localhost` is "well-known", that is, it is widely accepted that it resolves to loopback addresses – it doesn't just *happen to* resolve to 127.0.0.1 or ::1, it is *meant to* resolve to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 and it already has several decades of history doing so. So it is completely natural that an OS would have such a rule built-in.

   In fact even if you find a way to bypass Windows, you'll find that many *web browsers* also have such a rule built-in, regardless of what the OS does. (For example, here's [Chromium's source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/dns/host_resolver_manager.cc?dr=C&g=0&l=3048) showing that it has a hardcoded mapping for 'localhost' and won't even bother asking the OS.) There is even an IETF [draft standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-let-localhost-be-localhost/) which would mandate it at resolver level.
2. Web browsers often consider `localhost` to be a secure origin – they might provide more APIs for `http://localhost` than for other `http://` URLs. This of course means that allowing localhost to resolve to anything other than 127.0.0.1/::1 would be a security risk.